# How can I convert a standalone Scala application to runnable SOA?

Tags: java, linux, unix, apache-spark

I am working on a scala-spark application which I would like to migrate to the runnable service model.

For the application could be invoked but I would like to run the application as a service which could be stopped and stopped from a Unix/Linux command.

Also, deploy the application on webserver and build Rest APIs.

Would writing a wrapper in Linux/Unix make sense to run it as a detached daemon process?

Can someone guide me what is the right tools if any which could help me in rapid development?

Thanks,
Az

Comment: This is way too broad for SO standards. Sorry, I'm gonna vote to close this. Please narrow it down to one problem at a time and make it programming related. This is more of an architectural problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could :

- embed a REST API or whatever service you want into the driver
- use the livy project as you can see in the paypal presentation ["spark compute as a Service"][1] https://spark-summit.org/2017/events/spark-compute-as-a-service-at-paypal/

As for start stop restart and so on you need to track the applicationid to kill (assuming you are using yarn)

Answer (score 0):

1. To be stopped and started, you could use the thrift server and feed in straight SQL commands.  You could run a spark job that opens a listening port as well, which is what Zeppelin does.
2. To deploy the application it depends what language you like but you could use flask with Python or Play with Scala.

Also, you might want to look at Zeppelin, you can write the jobs on notebooks and then use the Zeppelin API to pipe in http requests.  Actually if you go this route, I'd be interested to look at your web service client because I'm goinng to be doing the same thing 
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/rest-api/rest-notebook.html

Comment: Thanks for the details. I was looking at various options. Was thinking of writing a wrapper but then it would need to written for each OS. A thrift server injection might make sense. I will explore.